# How can I set $PATH as part of spawing a process in node via node-pty?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are trying to encapsulate a very old command-line application which has these requirements:

1. the application must be launched from the location of our data files
   (i.e. the CWD is the data file directory)
2. the application exists at a location **not** in the default $PATH
3. the application launches sub-processes that expect the application path to be in $PATH
4. Due to 2 & 3, the application's path must be manually added to $PATH prior to launching it

So the normal way to run it is to `cd` to the data directory, add the application directory to the $PATH, and then run the application.  We can't just launch the application by its full path -- the $PATH must be set because the application expects to call other sub-processes in the same directory.  We don't have the ability to modify the application or its requirements.

The problem is this: how do I encapsulate the setting of $PATH and the launching of the application when spawning a process in node via node-pty.

```
var pty = require('node-pty');
// myapp lives in /usr/bin/app/
var term = pty.spawn("myapp", [], {
        cwd: '/usr/data/mydata'
      });
```

In short, I want the spawn to happen in the /usr/data/mydata directory, have /usr/bin/app/ added to $PATH, and myapp to get spawned, all in one shot.

Comment: alternately, you can write a bat file to the app dir, named with name of the path's executable and calling the full path; an alias so that extension-less invocations (which includes .bat) will run as expected, regardless of $PATH. i agree the environ change would be better, just tossing out a workaround in case you don't get an answer... for example, tool.exe called by tool.bat, tool.bat=`@c:\path\tool.exe %1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH is an environmental variable, so setting it with the env parameter should work.

```
var pty = require('node-pty');
// myapp lives in /usr/bin/app/
var term = pty.spawn("myapp", [], {
  cwd: '/usr/data/mydata',
  env: { PATH: '/usr/data/app:' + process.env.PATH }
});
```